# 10 sportsmen and 1 musician. Who’s next?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

- Ken Linseman
- John Entwistle
- Mansoor Ali Khan Pataudi
- Wayne Bartholomew
- Don Wilson
- Don Prudhomme
- Lou Gehrig
- Earl Manigault
- AN Hornby
- Doug Rader
- Glenn Robinson

**Who’s next and why?**

Because this question is slightly broad, I’ll tell you the specifics I
want:

> - Purdue University
>   - Basketball Coach
>   - Naismith Hall Of Fame

---

This should be fairly easy but if there are no answers in 1 week, I’ll give a hint.

<sub>*This is my first question on this site and I would greatly appreciate it if I was given some tips. I think this puzzle’s OK but if not then do let me know.*</sub>

Comment: Are the last 3 bullets a Hint? What do you mean by specifics?

Comment: The last 3 bullets are just part of the pattern. When I was researching for this puzzle I came across 2-3 people who could be the answer, so I gave some more info about the person I want as my answer.

Comment: Fairly easy and one week are **contradicting**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ken Linseman

> The Rat is his nickname

John Entwistle

> The Ox is his nickname

Mansoor Ali Khan Pataudi

> Tiger is his nickname

Wayne Bartholomew

> Rabbit is his nickname

Don Wilson

> The Dragon is his nickname

Don Prudhomme

> The Snake is his nickname

Lou Gehrig

> The Iron Horse is his nickname

Earl Manigault

> The Goat is his nickname

AN Hornby

> Monkey is his nickname

Doug Rader

> The Red Rooster is his nickname

Glenn Robinson

> Big Dog is his nickname

And

> Ward Lambert as mentioned by @Shinji Wins
> Piggy is his nickname

All are

> Famous people with an animal nickname that represent the 12 animals of
> The Chinese Zodiac (Thanks to @Paige Meinke)
> Rat, Ox, Tiger, Rabbit, Dragon, Snake, Horse, Goat, Monkey, Rooster, Dog and Pig

Comment: psst... nice work, but I think the reasoning he was looking for was [gur puvarfr mbqvnp](http://www.rot13.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Through a quick Google search and a bit of digging, I got my answer to be

> Ward Lambert

Because

> He was head basketball coach at Purdue University between 1916-1946, and was inducted into the Naismith Hall Of Fame in 1960. This should fill your criteria.

Comment: So whatb is the pattern?